# (VB) Suggestions with implementing a player shoot event

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently working on a game in Visual Basic similar to an arcade shooter. The player moves their ship left and right across the screen using the arrow keys, while they 'shoot' using the spacebar. Problem is, I'm not sure where to place the bullet's movement so it will constantly move (not just spawn on a key-down event) and be updated by the Render() function. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My current code is displayed below; it's my first time using a game loop, so apologies if anything's misused.

```
Public Class frmMain

'Diming drawing surface & controls
Dim g, bbg As Graphics
Dim backBuff As Bitmap
Dim keys(256) As Boolean
Dim clientWidth, clientHeight As Integer
Dim timer As Stopwatch
Dim interval, startTick As Long

'Diming playerShip
Dim playerSize As Long = 64
Dim playerShip As New Rectangle(180, 430, playerSize, playerSize)
Dim playerLoc As New Point(playerShip.Location)
Dim playerSpr As Image = My.Resources.sprPlayer
Dim playerSpeed As Long

'Diming playerBullet
Dim playerBulletWidth As Long = 9
Dim playerBulletHeight As Long = 20
Dim playerBullet As New Rectangle(playerLoc.X, playerLoc.Y - 20, playerBulletWidth, playerBulletHeight)
Dim playerBulletLoc As New Point(playerBullet.Location)
Dim playerBulletSpr As Image = My.Resources.sprPlayerBullet
Dim playerBulletSpeed As Long
Dim playerShoot As Boolean = False

Public Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Configuring specific properties of the form
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D
    'Me.BackColor = Color.Black

    'configuring timer controls
    interval = 16
    timer = New Stopwatch()

    'Assigning values to empty variables
    clientWidth = 450
    clientHeight = 550
    playerSpeed = 5
    playerBulletSpeed = 5

    'Configuring drawing surface
    g = Me.CreateGraphics
    backBuff = New Bitmap(clientWidth, clientHeight, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
    bbg = Graphics.FromImage(backBuff)

    'Initially draw playerShip
    bbg.DrawImage(playerSpr, playerShip)
    'bbg.DrawImage(playerBulletSpr, playerBullet)
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    keys(e.KeyCode) = True
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    keys(e.KeyCode) = False
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Shown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    GameLoop()
End Sub

Private Sub GameLoop()
    timer.Start()
    Do While (Me.Created)
        startTick = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
        GameLogic()
        Render()
        Application.DoEvents()

        'Allows game to run at constant speed on different machines
        Do While timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - startTick < interval
        Loop
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub GameLogic()
    'Spawning, movement & collision
    Dim keyPressed As Boolean = False

    'playerShip movement & shooting
    'Checks for no collision with form's right wall
    If Not playerShip.Location.X + playerSpeed > clientWidth - playerShip.Width - playerSpeed Then

        'Move playerShip right (right arrow)
        If keys(39) Then
            playerLoc = New Point(playerShip.Location.X + playerSpeed, playerShip.Location.Y)
            playerShip.Location = playerLoc
            keyPressed = True
        End If

    End If

    'Checks for no collision with form's left wall
    If Not playerShip.Location.X - playerSpeed < 0 Then

        'Move playerShip left (left arrow)
        If keys(37) Then
            playerLoc = New Point(playerShip.Location.X - playerSpeed, playerShip.Location.Y)
            playerShip.Location = playerLoc
            keyPressed = True
        End If

    End If

    'Launch bullet (space-bar)
    If keys(32) Then
        playerShoot = True
        keyPressed = True
        PlayerShipShoot()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PlayerShipShoot()
    'Add bullet activity here... maybe
End Sub

Private Sub Render()
    'Drawing playerShip & playerBullet
    bbg.DrawImage(playerSpr, playerShip)

    If playerShoot = True Then
        bbg.DrawImage(playerBulletSpr, playerBullet)
    End If

    'Drawing backBuff to the form
    g.DrawImage(backBuff, 0, 0)
    bbg.Clear(Color.Silver)
End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a class for the "bullet" would work here, with properties such as x and y position. when a spacebar press is detected, a new instance of the bullet class would be created with the current x and y pos, then on each loop where you are doing your other logic, you would call a method that would change the position properties, then draw it on the screen during your `Render()` sub. Could keep a `List(Of Bullets)` to keep multiple bullet objects going at once, and loop through the list in the `Render()` sub.

Comment: Trade out those `Long` datatypes for an `Integer` - not needed.

Comment: @RianBattle, Thanks for your suggestion, will give it a try!

Comment: I have always found the timer utility in the toolbox to be very helpful for game loops. I've always thrown things such as an obstacle's movements into a timer's "on-tick" function so the obstacle is constantly moving.